# Calculate column turn time averages in an Access Report

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-administration

This would be pretty simple in Excel but being relatively new to Access I'm not sure how to go about it.

I have about a dozen columns with data/time variables in them.

```
Project    Field1                   Field2        Field3        Field4
A          01/01/2015               01/02/2015                  01/04/2015 09:21:07 AM
B          01/01/2015 13:21:07 AM   02/01/2015   02/02/2015     03/01/2015
C          01/08/2015 12:21:07 AM   01/09/2015   03/01/2015     04/01/2015 11:21:07 AM
...        ...                      ...          ...            ...
```

I would like a report that gives me the average time (in days and hours, if listed) elapsing between the dates in Field1 and the dates in Field2, then Field2 to Field3, etc, but shows none of the data, only the aggregates.

So it should spit out something like this hh:mm:ss.

```
Field1 to Field2: 48:25:32
Field1 to Field3: 21:40:10
...
```

So I start with a query

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, FieldEtc
FROM tbl1
```

I tried to do the calculation in a GROUP BY, WHERE and ORDER BY clause but have been unsuccessful so far. I've also toyed with doing a select query then adding an expression in a report but wind up with the answer repeated once for every line of data the query returns.

```
=(Sum(DateDiff("d",[Field1],[Field2])))/(Count(*))
```

Can anyone throw me a bone here?

Comment: i don't see any time value to calculate elapsed time. moreover when you say "elapsed" i would think [end time] - [start time] = elapsed time?? 
or are they all elapsed time and you wan to find average between field1 & field2?

Comment: Average time between field1 and field2, then the average of those results which is what I'd like to display on the report.

Comment: you could use union query to join fieldA & FieldB and then find the average. same for other fields.

Comment: What is the syntax for finding an average within SQL?

Comment: Group it and use avg() function